# Watchkit create "bubble" interface like in messages app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Hey I am working on a messaging app with Apple Watch support.  [This video at 0:28 shows what I want to have](https://youtu.be/q29W7VPkIJ8?t=28s). Specifically, it's about the message bubbles and how they are resizing dynamically based on their screen position.

I am really surprised about not being able to find any project on Github that replicates this kind of interface and behavior. Do you know of/have any code available that looks somewhat comparable to the `messages` app on Apple Watch? It doesn't have to be exactly like this but everything that I could download and modify is better than what I would come up.

If I can't find anything I would probably draw some bubbles with text in it with Spritekit but having the resizing and all that would definitely not be efficient code if I wrote it so if you know of anything similar please tell me.

Comment: Why don't you just set the `Width` of the labels to `Size to fit content`, then you don't need to calculate or resize anything manually?

Comment: I am not so worried about the labels (I would defo try what you said, thanks) but about resizing the bubbles around them

Comment: How did you implement the bubbles so far? If they are images, then yes, the resizing can be more problematic, but for example if you are using a custom `WKInterfaceGroup` subclass, you can just set its size to `Size to fit content` as well and then the resizing will be handled automatically by WatchKit.